# Invalid AABB aabb

Tags: unity, physics, aabb, meshcollider, convex

```
Invalid AABB aabb      
UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility:CalculateSelectionBounds(Boolean, 
                                                                   Boolean)
```

I've got this error when I place any convex `mesh collider` in scene. **What does it mean?**

Game object also has `rigidbody` with `Use Gravity = true` and after run the scene i've got error:

> transform.position assign attempt for 'gameobject1' is not valid. Input position is { NaN, NaN, NaN }.

Comment: have you any script that "calculates" the position of 'gameobject1'? Input position is { NaN, NaN, NaN } smell of some unconsistent calculation

Comment: There aren't any scripts at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem like you have made the mistake (If your gameobject has a `transform`)
Try restarting Unity, rebooting your computer, reinstalling Unity.

Comment: Unity restart helped.

Answer (score 3):

So the aabb is the axis aligned bounding box and so if it is giving you errors about it that means that unity couldn't calculate the aabb of an object because either it's too small or to big or has some kind of negative size or doesn't have a transform.
Your other error is probably causing the invalid aabb error as the aabb does rely on the position of the object and is probably being thrown because you don't have a transform component on the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
    HealthBar.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(InitialWidthHealthBar * Player.pInstance.Health / 
        Player.pInstance.MaxHealth,HealthBar.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.y );
```

This is the code that produced the same error.Where the Player.pInstance.MaxHealth is 0. It means 100 / 0 , which cause mathematical error.I changed the Value to 100.its Working now.and i read the same will happen with tranform too.